# Merging files in TFS (team foundation server) for Visual studio .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a project that another programmer and I are trying to merge together.

The other programmer has a version that is 100% similar to the checked-in version on the TFS while I still have a version that has not been checked in yet.

Here is the result of running a comparison on both of the project:
[image: img1]

All the changes show up exactly where we expect them to be, so no issue there but instead of merging the two project it simply overwrites my work when I do a 'get'.

Here is what a comparison looks like on just one file, the change on the right is being added like it should, but the changes on the left that should be added as well are instead being deleted!:
[image: img2]

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated as I have to show it off tomorrow morning.

Comment: Any chance you are comparing the other way than you think you comparing? ( V.A vs. V.B will show adds, V.B vs. V.A will show the same change as delete)

Comment: To me it looks like you are doing a treediff, and not a merge when the conflicts appear. Can you show us the conflict instead? you are saying that you have two projects, but you mean that you have two versions of the same project, right? or are you trying to do a baseless merge?

Comment: Yes, I mean that I have two version of the same project that at one point were the same.

I'm not familiar with the term "baseless merge" but it sounds like what I want. Essentially, I want all changes to be merged together.